# Can I upload any File in Google Drive using Client ID & Client Secret, without using Token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to configure Google Drive API with Client ID & Client Secret. But don't want to generate Refresh Token.

Using Token, it is working fine. But without token I am using following code, but it asks me popup every time, with Authentication Fail Error.

```
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                       new ClientSecrets
                       {
                           ClientId = ClientId,
                           ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
                       },
                       new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                       "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;


            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```

Please help me for this.

Comment: The library is going to automatically create a refresh token for you and store it associated with your "user" parameter.  Without a refresh token its going to ask you for mission again.    You cant upload to Google without An access token.   Can you please explain what it is your trying to do i suspect you may be a little confused with Google Oauth and how it works

Comment: BTW GoogleWebAutorizationBroker is for installed applications it wont work if you try to host it as a asp.net application you need to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.

Answer (score 0):

From [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing):

> If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
>
> Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
>
> If Google determines that **your request and the token are valid**, it returns the requested data.
>
> Some flows include additional steps, such as **using refresh tokens to acquire new access tokens**. For detailed information about flows for various types of applications, see Google's [OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

So no, you can't upload a file to Google Drive if you solely have the user's credentials. You need a token.